# Why does my service principal not have access to my key vault?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

We have an existing key vault say kv1 and an existing ad security group say adg1.

adg1 already has an access policy set up that provides get and list access to members of the group.

Using an azure devops pipeline and an arm template we are deploying several resources including a vm scale set say vmss1

At the end, we call an azure automation job that has ad admin access to add vmss1 to adg1

vmss1 is not able to access the secrets in kv1.

If we instead add vmss1 service principal *directly* to the adg1, it will gain access, if we remove the direct addition, it loses access.

Our AD structure is not very complicated and we waited 2-3 hours for propagation and still nothing.

Here is the powershell that handles the adding:

```
$vmssid = (Get-AzureRMADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "$_scaleSetName").Id

if(!$vmssid){
    Write-Error 'Scale set did not exiset or was not a scale set'
    return 1
}

$groupId = (Get-AzureRMAdGroup -AzureRmContext $AzureContext -DisplayName "$webAppGroupName" ).Id 
if(!$groupId){
    Write-Error 'Group not found'
    return 1
}

$shouldAddMember = !(Get-AzureRMAdGroupMember -AzureRmContext $AzureContext -GroupObjectId $groupId | ?{$_.Id-eq $vmssid}) 
if($shouldAddMember ){
 Add-AzureRmAdGroupMember -AzureRmContext $AzureContext -MemberObjectId $vmssId -TargetGroupObjectId $groupId 
}
else{
Write-Output 'Member existed in group'
exit 0
}
```

The first run it results in the user getting added, subsequent runs print "Member existed"

Comment: Check it in the portal manually, is the service principal really existing in the group?

Comment: @JoyWang Yes, the service principal is in the group and the object Id's match between the MSI listed in the VMSS identity configuration blade and the active directory group membership blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the propagation time of azure AD can be extreme. 
After a day or it started working with just the AD group being assigned to the access policy. So I guess the answer is an excruciating amount of patience.